# android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders is not recognized in Kotlin code

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

For Java project, in order to recognize `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`, I simply define the following in my build gradle

### Java project

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

However, in Kotlin project, I can hardly make it recognizes `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`. I tried

### Kotlin project

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

It is still not able to recognize `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders`

[image]

The complete build.gradle is as follow - https://github.com/yccheok/AndroidDraw/blob/748baf44571c5b83d0c6e5b6a7137eef9cb17cdc/app/build.gradle

May I know, is there anything else I had missed out?

Comment: Try using androidx now. It is more stable and relaible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `kapt` you should also `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, Change in your viewmodel and extension version '1.1.0'

```
def lifecycle_version = "1.1.0" // change in this line

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
```

**Note : I have also using this kind of error message, but my problem was solved when I downgrade `version 1.1.1` with `version 1.1.0`.**

You need to check downgrade your version number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0,0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0'
```

This is what I am using right now as I converted to androidX.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We want to stick with support library at this moment, as our other projects are still using support libraries. We need to library link between different projects. We heard that support library doesn't play well with AndroidX.

Comment: Try one thing Go to Files > Invalidate cache and restart. Sometimes this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also need to remove from gradle.properties these lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked previously when it was not deprecated but for other developer's info. The Class has been deprecated and now you can directly user ViewModelProvider with constructor only.

For Further Info [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html)